# I want to change the date structure in ruby on rails. I just want to change it on run time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have printed date in booking summary using

```
<td colspan="2"><%= booking.created_at %></td>
```

It shows date like 2013-12-18 16:11:24 +0800 But, I want only 2013-12-18

Can you please direct me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [Time#strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) method

so your code would look like this:

```
<td colspan="2"><%= booking.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %></td>
```

or

```
<td colspan="2"><%= booking.created_at.strftime('%F') %></td>
```